# Fast factorization

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, factorization

> For a given number n (we know that n = p^a * q^b, for some prime numbers p,q and some integers a,b) and a given number φ(n) ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function ) find p,q,a and b.

The catch is that n, and φ(n) have about 200 digits so the algorithm have to be very fast.
It seems to be very hard problem and I completely don't know how to use φ(n).

How to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `n = p^a * q^b`, the totient is `φ(n) = (p-1)*p^(a-1) * (q-1)*q^(b-1)`. Without loss of generality, `p < q`.

So `gcd(n,φ(n)) = p^(a-1) * q^(b-1)` if `p` does not divide `q-1` and `gcd(n,φ(n)) = p^a * q^(b-1)` if `p` divides `q-1`.

In the first case, we have `n/gcd(n,φ(n)) = p*q` and `φ(n)/gcd(n,φ(n)) = (p-1)*(q-1) = p*q + 1 - (p+q)`, thus you have `x = p*q = n/gcd(n,φ(n))` and `y = p+q = n/gcd(n,φ(n)) + 1 - φ(n)/gcd(n,φ(n))`. Then finding `p` and `q` is simple: `y^2 - 4*x = (q-p)^2`, so `q = (y + sqrt(y^2 - 4*x))/2`, and `p = y-q`. Then finding the exponents `a` and `b` is trivial.

In the second case, `n/gcd(n,φ(n)) = q`. Then you can easily find the exponent `b`, dividing by `q` until the division leaves a remainder, and thus obtain `p^a`. Dividing `φ(n)` by `(q-1)*q^(b-1)` gives you `z = (p-1)*p^(a-1)`. Then `p^a - z = p^(a-1)` and `p = p^a/(p^a-z)`. Finding the exponent `a` is again trivial.

So it remains to decide which case you have. You have case 2 if and only if `n/gcd(n,φ(n))` is a prime.

For that, you need a decent primality test. Or you can first suppose that you have case 1, and if that doesn't work out, conclude that you have case 2.

Comment: Basically, you need to know the formula for the totient, and that you want to find `p*q` and `p+q`. From then on, you just shuffle the ingredients until the desired result comes out.

Comment: Also there is case 3: `gcd(n,φ(n)) = p^(a-1) * q^b`

Comment: @SaeedAmiri With regards to case 3, since I arbitrarily named `p` and `q` such that `p < q`, that can't happen, `q` cannot divide `p-1`.

Comment: Ok I didn't see your `p<q` assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try working out what n / (n - φ(n)) is.

Follow up:

n / (n - φ(n)) = pq.  You just keep dividing n by pq.

Comment: That's not correct. `φ(6) = 2`, `6 - φ(6) = 4` doesn't even divide 6.

Comment: I calculate that `n / (n - φ(n)) = pq/(q+p-1)`.  I guess it's not so basic.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, right it works. That's interesting, any suggestions why does it work, how to deduce this formula?

Comment: @xan: You can just use the equation on the wiki-page you linked, and do a bit of algebra.

Comment: Yes, I got the details wrong, but the principle is correct. Let x be the highest common factor of n and φ(n). Then there are three possibilities: n = px, n=qx and n = pqx, φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1)x. These are all easily solved.